# Is it good to create a usercontrol for Recursive code in xaml?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

```
<Border BorderBrush="#C4C8CC" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="SectionTitle" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#3D3D3D"  />
    </Border>
```

I have to use the same above format at many places in a single xaml page, so for this i created a usercontrol and defined the above code inside it.

So my question is,
What i am doing is it right approach?
Will it make the page to load slower then the above code used as it is without defining it in a new user control?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you would notice a difference.  However a lighter and more flexiable approach would be to use a Templated Control instead of a UserControl.  Its a little more technical but results in a tighter implementation.

How many is "many" anyhow?